# Using a back level library with a proprietary application but without effecting the rest of my install base

Tags: linux, libraries, version

I have Corel AfterShot Pro 3 for my photo workflow management but it stopped working a year or so ago. I thought I'd wait for Corel to get current with their application, using up-to-date libraries. I have been waiting in vain and now I have many gigabytes of photos waiting to be processed and catalogued. The problem is that when I install it (I use OpenSuse Tumbleweed's zypper to install the downloaded rpm) I get

```
AfterShot3X64 
Install Path:           /opt/AfterShot3(64-bit)
LD_PATH:                /opt/AfterShot3(64-bit)/lib:
XLIB_SKIP_ARGB_VISUALS:
./AfterShot: error while loading shared libraries: libgstreamer-0.10.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've created symbolic links from `/usr/lib64/libgstreamer-1.0.so.0` to both

- `/usr/lib64/libgstreamer-0.10.so.0` (my general library location)
- `/opt/AfterShotPro3(64-bit)/lib/libgstreamer-0.10.so.0` (the location of the downloaded app's own libraries)

I've got to say that despite Corel's shameful reputation for fixing bugs (and Linux support, despite this originally being a Linux product - Bibble Pro), I had hopes that they'd put SOME effort into keeping up-to-date with library code.

Does anyone have any ideas on what I could do. I wondered whether there's a way to find and install the versions of the library files it's complaining about and installing them where AfterShot can find them but which won't mangle the more up-to-date libraries in `/usr/lib64`

Having received @hermann 's response I tried the following:

1. I found a OpenSuSe Tumbleweed YMP to download
2. Then

```
rpm --prefix="/opt/AfterShot3(64-bit)/lib" -ivh /home/greg/Downloads/libgstreamer-0_10-0.ymp
Retrieving https://build.opensuse.org/staging_workflows/openSUSE:Factory
Retrieving https://build.opensuse.org/package/view_file/openSUSE:Factory:Staging/dashboard/devel_projects
Retrieving http://en.opensuse.org/Portal:Factory
Retrieving https://build.opensuse.org/staging_workflows/openSUSE:Factory
Retrieving https://build.opensuse.org/package/view_file/openSUSE:Factory:Staging/dashboard/devel_projects
Retrieving http://en.opensuse.org/Portal:Factory
error: open of <metapackage failed: No such file or directory
error: open of xmlns:os=http://opensuse.org/Standards/One_Click_Install failed: No such file or directory
error: open of xmlns=http://opensuse.org/Standards/One_Click_Install> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <group failed: No such file or directory
error: open of distversion=openSUSE Tumbleweed> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <repositories> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <repository failed: No such file or directory
error: open of recommended=true> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <name>home:cabelo:games</name> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <summary>Games failed: No such file or directory
error: open of for failed: No such file or directory
error: open of GNU/Linux failed: No such file or directory
error: open of plataform</summary> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <description></description> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <url>https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/cabelo:/games/openSUSE_Tumbleweed/</url> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of </repository> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <repository failed: No such file or directory
error: open of recommended=true> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <name>openSUSE:Factory</name> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <summary>The failed: No such file or directory
error: open of next failed: No such file or directory
error: open of openSUSE failed: No such file or directory
error: open of distribution</summary> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <description>Any failed: No such file or directory
error: open of user failed: No such file or directory
error: open of who failed: No such file or directory
error: open of wishes failed: No such file or directory
error: open of to failed: No such file or directory
error: open of have failed: No such file or directory
error: open of the failed: No such file or directory
error: open of newest failed: No such file or directory
error: open of packages failed: No such file or directory
error: open of that failed: No such file or directory
error: open of include, failed: No such file or directory
error: open of but failed: No such file or directory
error: open of are failed: No such file or directory
error: open of not failed: No such file or directory
error: open of limited failed: No such file or directory
error: open of to, failed: No such file or directory
error: open of the failed: No such file or directory
error: open of Linux failed: No such file or directory
error: open of kernel, failed: No such file or directory
error: open of SAMBA, failed: No such file or directory
error: open of git, failed: No such file or directory
error: open of desktops, failed: No such file or directory
error: open of office failed: No such file or directory
error: open of applications failed: No such file or directory
error: open of and failed: No such file or directory
error: open of many failed: No such file or directory
error: open of other failed: No such file or directory
error: open of packages, failed: No such file or directory
error: open of will failed: No such file or directory
error: open of want failed: No such file or directory
error: open of Tumbleweed. failed: No such file or directory
error: open of Tumbleweed failed: No such file or directory
error: open of appeals failed: No such file or directory
error: open of to failed: No such file or directory
error: open of Power failed: No such file or directory
error: open of Users, failed: No such file or directory
error: open of Software failed: No such file or directory
error: open of Developers failed: No such file or directory
error: open of and failed: No such file or directory
error: open of openSUSE failed: No such file or directory
error: open of Contributors. failed: No such file or directory
error: open of If failed: No such file or directory
error: open of you failed: No such file or directory
error: open of require failed: No such file or directory
error: open of the failed: No such file or directory
error: open of latest failed: No such file or directory
error: open of software failed: No such file or directory
error: open of stacks failed: No such file or directory
error: open of and failed: No such file or directory
error: open of Integrated failed: No such file or directory
error: open of Development failed: No such file or directory
error: open of Environment failed: No such file or directory
error: open of or failed: No such file or directory
error: open of need failed: No such file or directory
error: open of a failed: No such file or directory
error: open of stable failed: No such file or directory
error: open of platform failed: No such file or directory
error: open of closest failed: No such file or directory
error: open of to failed: No such file or directory
error: open of bleeding failed: No such file or directory
error: open of edge failed: No such file or directory
error: open of Linux, failed: No such file or directory
error: open of Tumbleweed failed: No such file or directory
error: open of is failed: No such file or directory
error: open of the failed: No such file or directory
error: open of best failed: No such file or directory
error: open of choice failed: No such file or directory
error: open of for failed: No such file or directory
error: open of you. failed: No such file or directory
error: open of Staging failed: No such file or directory
error: open of dashboard failed: No such file or directory
error: open of is failed: No such file or directory
error: open of located failed: No such file or directory
error: open of at: failed: No such file or directory
error: /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.6Ufc8q: not an rpm package (or package manifest): 
error: open of List failed: No such file or directory
error: open of of failed: No such file or directory
error: open of known failed: No such file or directory
error: open of devel failed: No such file or directory
error: open of projects: failed: No such file or directory
error: /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.Ra4jZS: not an rpm package (or package manifest): 
error: open of Have failed: No such file or directory
error: open of a failed: No such file or directory
error: open of look failed: No such file or directory
error: open of at failed: No such file or directory
error: /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.3yLYKL: not an rpm package (or package manifest): 
error: open of for failed: No such file or directory
error: open of more failed: No such file or directory
error: open of details.</description> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <url>http://download.opensuse.org/tumbleweed/repo/oss/</url> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of </repository> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <repository failed: No such file or directory
error: open of recommended=true> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <name>openSUSE:Tumbleweed</name> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <summary>Tumbleweed</summary> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <description>Tumbleweed failed: No such file or directory
error: open of is failed: No such file or directory
error: open of the failed: No such file or directory
error: open of openSUSE failed: No such file or directory
error: open of Rolling failed: No such file or directory
error: open of Release failed: No such file or directory
error: open of This failed: No such file or directory
error: open of OBS failed: No such file or directory
error: open of Project failed: No such file or directory
error: open of represents failed: No such file or directory
error: open of the failed: No such file or directory
error: open of content failed: No such file or directory
error: open of of failed: No such file or directory
error: open of the failed: No such file or directory
error: open of currently failed: No such file or directory
error: open of published failed: No such file or directory
error: open of snapshot. failed: No such file or directory
error: open of The failed: No such file or directory
error: open of newer failed: No such file or directory
error: open of repository failed: No such file or directory
error: open of for failed: No such file or directory
error: open of next failed: No such file or directory
error: open of publish failed: No such file or directory
error: open of can failed: No such file or directory
error: open of be failed: No such file or directory
error: open of found failed: No such file or directory
error: open of in failed: No such file or directory
error: open of openSUSE:Factory failed: No such file or directory
error: open of standard failed: No such file or directory
error: open of repository. failed: No such file or directory
error: open of </description> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <url>https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/openSUSE:/Tumbleweed/standard/</url> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of </repository> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <repository failed: No such file or directory
error: open of recommended=true> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <name>openSUSE:Tumbleweed</name> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <summary>Tumbleweed</summary> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <description>Tumbleweed failed: No such file or directory
error: open of is failed: No such file or directory
error: open of the failed: No such file or directory
error: open of openSUSE failed: No such file or directory
error: open of Rolling failed: No such file or directory
error: open of Release failed: No such file or directory
error: open of This failed: No such file or directory
error: open of OBS failed: No such file or directory
error: open of Project failed: No such file or directory
error: open of represents failed: No such file or directory
error: open of the failed: No such file or directory
error: open of content failed: No such file or directory
error: open of of failed: No such file or directory
error: open of the failed: No such file or directory
error: open of currently failed: No such file or directory
error: open of published failed: No such file or directory
error: open of snapshot. failed: No such file or directory
error: open of The failed: No such file or directory
error: open of newer failed: No such file or directory
error: open of repository failed: No such file or directory
error: open of for failed: No such file or directory
error: open of next failed: No such file or directory
error: open of publish failed: No such file or directory
error: open of can failed: No such file or directory
error: open of be failed: No such file or directory
error: open of found failed: No such file or directory
error: open of in failed: No such file or directory
error: open of openSUSE:Factory failed: No such file or directory
error: open of standard failed: No such file or directory
error: open of repository. failed: No such file or directory
error: open of </description> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <url>http://download.opensuse.org/tumbleweed/repo/oss/</url> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of </repository> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <repository failed: No such file or directory
error: open of recommended=false> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <name>openSUSE:Factory</name> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <summary>The failed: No such file or directory
error: open of next failed: No such file or directory
error: open of openSUSE failed: No such file or directory
error: open of distribution</summary> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <description>Any failed: No such file or directory
error: open of user failed: No such file or directory
error: open of who failed: No such file or directory
error: open of wishes failed: No such file or directory
error: open of to failed: No such file or directory
error: open of have failed: No such file or directory
error: open of the failed: No such file or directory
error: open of newest failed: No such file or directory
error: open of packages failed: No such file or directory
error: open of that failed: No such file or directory
error: open of include, failed: No such file or directory
error: open of but failed: No such file or directory
error: open of are failed: No such file or directory
error: open of not failed: No such file or directory
error: open of limited failed: No such file or directory
error: open of to, failed: No such file or directory
error: open of the failed: No such file or directory
error: open of Linux failed: No such file or directory
error: open of kernel, failed: No such file or directory
error: open of SAMBA, failed: No such file or directory
error: open of git, failed: No such file or directory
error: open of desktops, failed: No such file or directory
error: open of office failed: No such file or directory
error: open of applications failed: No such file or directory
error: open of and failed: No such file or directory
error: open of many failed: No such file or directory
error: open of other failed: No such file or directory
error: open of packages, failed: No such file or directory
error: open of will failed: No such file or directory
error: open of want failed: No such file or directory
error: open of Tumbleweed. failed: No such file or directory
error: open of Tumbleweed failed: No such file or directory
error: open of appeals failed: No such file or directory
error: open of to failed: No such file or directory
error: open of Power failed: No such file or directory
error: open of Users, failed: No such file or directory
error: open of Software failed: No such file or directory
error: open of Developers failed: No such file or directory
error: open of and failed: No such file or directory
error: open of openSUSE failed: No such file or directory
error: open of Contributors. failed: No such file or directory
error: open of If failed: No such file or directory
error: open of you failed: No such file or directory
error: open of require failed: No such file or directory
error: open of the failed: No such file or directory
error: open of latest failed: No such file or directory
error: open of software failed: No such file or directory
error: open of stacks failed: No such file or directory
error: open of and failed: No such file or directory
error: open of Integrated failed: No such file or directory
error: open of Development failed: No such file or directory
error: open of Environment failed: No such file or directory
error: open of or failed: No such file or directory
error: open of need failed: No such file or directory
error: open of a failed: No such file or directory
error: open of stable failed: No such file or directory
error: open of platform failed: No such file or directory
error: open of closest failed: No such file or directory
error: open of to failed: No such file or directory
error: open of bleeding failed: No such file or directory
error: open of edge failed: No such file or directory
error: open of Linux, failed: No such file or directory
error: open of Tumbleweed failed: No such file or directory
error: open of is failed: No such file or directory
error: open of the failed: No such file or directory
error: open of best failed: No such file or directory
error: open of choice failed: No such file or directory
error: open of for failed: No such file or directory
error: open of you. failed: No such file or directory
error: open of Staging failed: No such file or directory
error: open of dashboard failed: No such file or directory
error: open of is failed: No such file or directory
error: open of located failed: No such file or directory
error: open of at: failed: No such file or directory
error: /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.WmK053: not an rpm package (or package manifest): 
error: open of List failed: No such file or directory
error: open of of failed: No such file or directory
error: open of known failed: No such file or directory
error: open of devel failed: No such file or directory
error: open of projects: failed: No such file or directory
error: /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.SOLsQU: not an rpm package (or package manifest): 
error: open of Have failed: No such file or directory
error: open of a failed: No such file or directory
error: open of look failed: No such file or directory
error: open of at failed: No such file or directory
error: /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.iO0DaZ: not an rpm package (or package manifest): 
error: open of for failed: No such file or directory
error: open of more failed: No such file or directory
error: open of details.</description> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <url>https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/openSUSE:/Factory/ports/</url> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of </repository> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of </repositories> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <software> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <item> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <name>libgstreamer-0_10-0</name> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <summary>Streaming-Media failed: No such file or directory
error: open of Framework failed: No such file or directory
error: open of Runtime</summary> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <description>GStreamer failed: No such file or directory
error: open of is failed: No such file or directory
error: open of a failed: No such file or directory
error: open of streaming-media failed: No such file or directory
error: open of framework, failed: No such file or directory
error: open of based failed: No such file or directory
error: open of on failed: No such file or directory
error: open of graphs failed: No such file or directory
error: open of of failed: No such file or directory
error: open of filters failed: No such file or directory
error: open of which failed: No such file or directory
error: open of operate failed: No such file or directory
error: open of on failed: No such file or directory
error: open of media failed: No such file or directory
error: open of data. failed: No such file or directory
error: open of Applications failed: No such file or directory
error: open of using failed: No such file or directory
error: open of this failed: No such file or directory
error: open of library failed: No such file or directory
error: open of can failed: No such file or directory
error: open of do failed: No such file or directory
error: open of anything failed: No such file or directory
error: open of from failed: No such file or directory
error: open of real-time failed: No such file or directory
error: open of sound failed: No such file or directory
error: open of processing failed: No such file or directory
error: open of to failed: No such file or directory
error: open of playing failed: No such file or directory
error: open of videos, failed: No such file or directory
error: open of and failed: No such file or directory
error: open of just failed: No such file or directory
error: open of about failed: No such file or directory
error: open of anything failed: No such file or directory
error: open of else failed: No such file or directory
error: open of media-related. failed: No such file or directory
error: open of Its failed: No such file or directory
error: open of plug-in-based failed: No such file or directory
error: open of architecture failed: No such file or directory
error: open of means failed: No such file or directory
error: open of that failed: No such file or directory
error: open of new failed: No such file or directory
error: open of data failed: No such file or directory
error: open of types failed: No such file or directory
error: open of or failed: No such file or directory
error: open of processing failed: No such file or directory
error: open of capabilities failed: No such file or directory
error: open of can failed: No such file or directory
error: open of be failed: No such file or directory
error: open of added failed: No such file or directory
error: open of by failed: No such file or directory
error: open of installing failed: No such file or directory
error: open of new failed: No such file or directory
error: open of plug-ins.</description> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of </item> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of </software> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of </group> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of </metapackage> failed: No such file or directory
```

Comment: I'm guessing I'm on a losing streak here?

Answer (score 1):

While creating symbolic links can help, but only in a rather limited set of situations. It is quite probable that the new version of the shared object is ought to be used in a slightly different manner than the old one. That is what a change in the version number is indicating, after all.

What you want is a collection of the necessary libraries and the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

In case of a distribution with versioned releases, you may obtain the old libraries via the package archives. For Ubuntu, I occasionally use https://packages.ubuntu.com/. You can search for the exact file name and download the appropriate .deb file. You can then use `dpkg -x file.deb /opt/AfterShotPro3(64-bit)/oldlibs/` to extract all the files. Repeat this for all problematic libraries. You may need to do this for the libraries' dependencies, too. There is a limit, though. From personal experience, I can tell: If old libraries depend on an old version of libc and refuse to use the currently installed one, you are running out of luck.

Then, instead of executing `/opt/AfterShotPro3(64-bit)/bin/aftershotopro` (I completely made up the executable name), set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` first: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/AfterShotPro3(64-bit)/oldlibs/ /opt/AfterShotPro3(64-bit)/bin/aftershotopro`